# Как расширить Box до внешних границ в Java

Tags: java

```
public class SimpleWindow extends JFrame {
    SimpleWindow(){
    //Main Window
    super("Testing");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(900, 500);


    // MAIN JTabbedPane
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP, JTabbedPane.WRAP_TAB_LAYOUT);



        //TEST TAB
        JPanel testtab = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.add("testtab", testtab);

        //Test Box
        Box testbox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        testbox.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Settings"));

        JComboBox main_status_levelsa = new JComboBox(elementsa);
        main_status_levelsa.setSelectedIndex(0);
        testbox.add(main_status_levelsa);
        testbox.add(new JCheckBox("Use present time."));     


        testtab.add(testbox, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я Новенький в этом, поэтому буду рад любому совету :) Это только часть кода, думаю весь не имеет смысл скидывать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вдруг у кого возникнет такой же вопрос, то получилось с помощью:

```
    boxname.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(1100, 300));
    boxname.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1100, 100));
    boxname.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1100, 200));
    boxname.setSize(1100, 200);
```